# Kotlin - How can i return different types from my method?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have this method:

```
private fun getOffer(offers: OfferRepresentation, type: OfferType): ???? {
    return when (type) {
        OfferType.ADDON -> offers.addon 
        OfferType.SALE -> offers.sale
        OfferType.PLAN -> offers.plan
        OfferType.CUSTOMPLAN -> offers.customPlan
    }
}
```

How can i change this method to return the correct type?

Comment: What does the OfferRepresentation class look like?

Comment: @fejd OfferRepresentation has four attributes (offerTypes) that can be a addon, sale, plan or customPlan. If OfferRepresentation has a plan (or any other), the others attributes are aways null.

Answer (score 11):

It's hard to give you a difinitive answer without you giving more info, but the easiest way to return multiple types is to have them all share an interface or superclass:

```
interface Offer

class Addon : Offer
class Sale : Offer
class Plan : Offer
class CustomPlan : Offer
```

You can also use a `sealed class` if your options are static, it just depends on your use case.  Either way, you can then just have the function return type be `Offer`

For more information see:

- [Interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html)
- [Sealed Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)

Comment: If you cannot control the classes, how would you do that? eg. either String, Int or Float

Comment: @CLOVIS if you really are going to return *anything*, you can just use `Any` as the return type.

Answer (score 6):

You have the trivial solution of using `Any` as your return type. `Any` is not exactly like `Object` in Java but it's close enough in this case (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html):

> All classes in Kotlin have a common superclass **Any**, that is a default
>   super for a class with no supertypes declared:
>
> ```
> class Example // Implicitly inherits from Any
> ```

So if your return types are completely unrelated and it doesn't make sense for you to make them share a common interface, then you can use Any:

```
private fun getOffer(offers: OfferRepresentation, type: OfferType): Any {
    return when (type) {
        OfferType.ADDON -> offers.addon 
        OfferType.SALE -> offers.sale
        OfferType.PLAN -> offers.plan
        OfferType.CUSTOMPLAN -> offers.customPlan
    }
```

Comment: What if you want to be able to return `Any` and `Any?`

Those are treated differently by the Kt compiler

Comment: @kzs In that case you can return `Any?`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do that:

```
object Main {

    // concrete class for all "enum" values (such as OfferType.ADDON or OfferType.SALE)
    // that get passed to `getOffer` as second param
    class OfferType<T> {

        companion object Types {

            // "enum" values. Unfortunately Kotlin doesn't support
            // type parameters for real enums
            @JvmStatic
            val ADDON = OfferType<Addon>()

            @JvmStatic
            val SALE = OfferType<Sale>()

            data class Addon(val name: String)
            data class Sale(val name: String)
        }
    }

    data class OfferRepresentation(
        val addon: OfferType.Types.Addon,
        val sale: OfferType.Types.Sale
    )

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        fun <T> getOffer(offers: OfferRepresentation, type: OfferType<T>): T {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return when (type) {
                OfferType.ADDON -> offers.addon as T
                OfferType.SALE -> offers.sale as T
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type $type")
            }
        }

        val offer = OfferRepresentation(
            OfferType.Types.Addon("addon"),
            OfferType.Types.Sale("sale")
        )

        // types are specified explicitly for the sake of demonstration
        val addon: OfferType.Types.Addon = getOffer(offer, OfferType.ADDON)
        val sale: OfferType.Types.Sale = getOffer(offer, OfferType.SALE)

        println("$addon, $sale")
    }
}
```

Note that there is an `UNCHECKED_CAST` in `getOffer` function. It's your responsibility to ensure that `OfferType.ADDON` (`OfferType.SALE`, etc) values are parameterized with the correct `OfferRepresentation`'s field type and `when` logic is also correct, otherwise you'll get `ClassCast` exception in runtime.

---

**UPD**. There is alternative implementation that uses a bit of kotlin magic, specifically, [reified types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).  With this approach instead of having separate entities to define the field that you want to be returned from `getOffer` function you just specify explicit type parameter. Alternatively you can rely on implicit type inference:

```
object Main2 {

    object OfferType {
        data class Addon(val name: String)
        data class Sale(val name: String)
    }

    data class OfferRepresentation(
        val addon: OfferType.Addon,
        val sale: OfferType.Sale
    )

    //reified type parameters require function to be inline
    inline fun <reified T> getOffer(offers: OfferRepresentation): T {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return when (T::class) {
            OfferType.Addon::class -> offers.addon as T
            OfferType.Sale::class -> offers.sale as T
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type ${T::class}")
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val offer = OfferRepresentation(
            OfferType.Addon("addon"),
            OfferType.Sale("sale")
        )

        // types needed to be specified explicitly here
        val addon: OfferType.Addon = getOffer(offer)
        val sale: OfferType.Sale = getOffer(offer)

        // alternatively `getOffer` should be invoked like this:
        getOffer<OfferType.Addon>(offer)

        println("$addon, $sale")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot return more than 1 value from a function by the JVM. 
What you can do is return a Pair or Tuple or create a Data class with all the fields and then have them as optional

Eg:

data class Offer(val type1: String?=null, val type2: Integer? = 0)